# How to execute this for loop in R

Tags: for-loop

```
# Load required libraries
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lmtest)
library(tidyquant)


# Set the start and end date for historical data
end_date <- as.Date("2023-09-18")
start_date <- end_date - 5*365  # 5 years of historical data

# Define the S&P 500 index symbol
sp500 <- "^GSPC"

# Define a list of the 20 biggest stocks
top_20_stocks <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "GOOG","TSLA", "JPM", "JNJ", "META", "BRK-A",
                    "NVDA", "V", "PG", "UNH", "MA", "PYPL", "HD", "INTC", "ASML", "ADBE")

# Replace double quotes with single quotes
top_20_stocks_for <- gsub('"', "", top_20_stocks)

# Define the symbol for the 10-Year U.S. Treasury Constant Maturity Rate
tnx_symbol <- "^TNX"

getSymbols(sp500, from = start_date, to = end_date, auto.assign = TRUE)

getSymbols(top_20_stocks, from = start_date, to = end_date, auto.assign = TRUE)

getSymbols(tnx_symbol, from = start_date, to = end_date, auto.assign = TRUE)

sp500_daily_return <- dailyReturn(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted)

stocks_daily_returns <- list()

for (symbol in top_20_stocks_for) {
  stocks_daily_returns[[symbol]] <- dailyReturn(symbol$symbol.Adjusted)
}
```

WHY DOES MY FOR LOOP DOESN'T WORK??

Tried alot of things, but everytime get the same error:Error in symbol$symbol.Adjusted :
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

# Get daily returns for all stocks with Tidyquant

df <- top_20_stocks %>% 
  tq_get(from = start_date, to = end_date) %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
               period = "daily", 
               col_rename = "daily_ra")

# Plot

df %>%  
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = date, y = daily_ra, col = symbol) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ symbol)
```

[image]